# gsmComm library Error

Tags: c#

i was checking the sample code with gsmComm library, my modem is Nokia N70 Modem and the connection was done successfuly and i am sending msg from it too but when i tried to read sms or contacts through application .. i got this message

"Error: Phone reports generic communication error or syntax error. (GsmComm.GsmCommunication.CommException)"

what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used other nokia phone (E51) the other day and got the same problem. After googling somewhere found that AT command for reading is not supported in my phone. you could check if your N70. I believe it doesn't support AT command for reading as well .

Answer (score 0):

Wow... ive seen this a LITTLE LATE :P but lemme know if i can help.
Can you post the last most relevant lines of code just before it throws the error?

Are you sure you didnt mess about with the settings? or maybe you need to experiment with some other settings to get it to work.

Please post your initialization code too... (if i remember correctly its only 2 to 4 lines of code...)